Api call works fine in Postman but does not work in PHP CURL
I have an API that works fine in postman. But i try the same API in PHP CURL, no way to make it work.
Here is a screenshot of postman declaration :

Here is the PHP version

<?php

$data = array(
'prompt' => "write me a poem",
'use_buffer' => 1);
   

$api_url="https://myserver.com" ;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data) );

/*curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));*/

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: ' . len($data)));
      
$response = curl_exec($ch);
       
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
print("<br>");

Thanks for any feedback

You don't seem to be using JSON with Postman.

Post data in the url as query params instead of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Whenever this situation happens try to generate code snippets in Postman

Thanks as you suggested postman code snippets is aligned with your tips : curl --location --request POST 'https://myserver.com?prompt=write%20me%20a%20poem&use_buffer=1'

when i use the prompt parameter, the query works, but i absolutely a POST api because i need to submit like 20k tokens of text.

Problems in the code

Missing Content-Type Header: The request sends data in JSON format but doesn't specify it in the headers.
Potential Server Misinterpretation: Without the Content-Type header, the server might not understand the JSON data correctly.

PHP CURL POST request code with corrections
<?php

// Your data to be sent
$data = array(
    'prompt' => "write me a poem",
    'use_buffer' => 1
);

// The URL of the API
$api_url = "https://myserver.com";

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// Disable SSL verification (not recommended for production)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Set the data to be sent in the request body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

// Specify the headers for the request
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
print("<br>");

?>


Thanks for your solution, i have tried it but it seems that the api does not receive the prompt parameters, as VLAZ said, the api work when i put the pamaters in url.

@popabig, I tested the code above and it seems to be working properly. Could you please provide the code for your API side as well?
